# Making a rewriterule remove .php extension?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have come up with a rewriterule to to go to any page on my website without typing in the .php extension because it is automatically added to the url.

The rule is: RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /$1.php

It takes anything you type in my index and adds .php to it, so you can put in http://sampardee.com/index and it pulls up index.php

Now my question is how to detect when a user enters http://sampardee.com/index.php and change it to http://sampardee.com/index

How could I do so with a rewriterule?

Answer (score 3):

You need to force a redirect on the user *without* matching the internal redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /$1.php
```

This redirects the user with a `301 Moved Permanently` redirection to the modified URL.

Comment: You may need to toy around with RewriteCond's then so that both rules won't match at the same time, but the scenario you described should be doable with rewrites.

Comment: I fixed my answer, it won't loop now (you have to check with a RewriteCond whether it is already a redirect or not).

Comment: It's better to use `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""` as this prevents the rule form matching on the internal redirect done for an `ErrorDocument` directive.