# how to redirect url?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using apache2 + tomcat on ubuntu 10.4. I am running on tomcat server that has webapps listening on 8080

trying to redirect **domain.com/category/post-name.html** 
to new url >

> **domain.com/newcategory/blogs/category/post-name**

what is the best possible way to achive this?

so far I have...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-z0-9]+/[a-zA-z0-9]+/(.*)?\.html$
RewriteRule ^/[a-zA-z0-9]+/[a-zA-z0-9]+/(.*)?\.html$ http://www.domain.com/newcategory/blogs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite), [How to remove file extension from website address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address-sample-photos-attached), [remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess), and dozens more.

Comment: well, thank you for the links.  I have checked them out.  However, I am not only trying to get rid of just the ".html" part - I need to properly redirect over 20,000 posts the url redirect above seems as it would do the trick, but it doesnt work.  So, I am trying to figure out if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **post-name** carries over to the redirected URL, and so does the **category**, but the **newcategory/blogs** part would have to be hardcoded because there's nothing to pull that from the old URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newcategory/blogs
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/newcategory/blogs/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```