# Automatic URL Rewriting not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to hide .php extension so I wrote following code in .htaccess file which I found at this link [How to remove file extension from website address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This work fine when I type localhost/testsite/index it displays correctly localhost/testsite/index.php and display localhost/testsite/index in address bar as I want, 
but when I forcefully type localhost/testsite/index.php it does not converted to localhost/testsite/index. I want to remove extension even when user type .php after page name.

Comment: I am afraid you cant. I have more than average experience with htaccess files and it works the way you wrote. You can still access the full path instead of the rewriten if you write it manually and i dont see anything wrong in there! :)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: in stackoverflow site for example if i write 
stackoverflow.com/questions/25636602/automatic-url-rewriting-not-working.php?noredirect=1#comment40055522_25636602 
it will display 
stackoverflow.com/questions/25636602/automatic-url-rewriting-not-working?noredirect=1#comment40055522_25636602
and will remove .php extension.

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```