# remove and disallow extensions with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I found this script or removing extensions from php files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

While this works, it still allows files to be accessed if you type them in *with* their extension, which I don't want.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I also tried `^(.*)$` and `^(.+)$`

which seems like it should do the job, because it would do this:

```
index.php -> index.php.php
```

but somehow, it doesn't work as expected.

So how do I update the above .htaccess script to disallow file extensions?

EDIT:

My .htaccess script seems to be detecting the files correctly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "^.*\.php$" "other.html" [L]
RewriteRule "^([^\.]+)$" "other2.html" [L]
```

The pages other.html and other2.html simply contain the words "OTHER" and "OTHER 2"

Now, using the above script, the output is as expected:

```
"/test.php" gives output "OTHER"
"/test" gives "OTHER 2"
```

but if I update the script to the following, both url variations start returning "OTHER"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "^.*\.php$" "other.html" [L]
RewriteRule "^([^\.]+)$" "$1.php" [L]      // changed
```

So it seems that after the extensionless filename has ".php" added to it by rule#2, it somehow gets caught by rule #1.

Aren't these rules ordered? and isn't [L] supposed to stop processing on a match?

**EDIT 2:**
So assuming `[L]` did what I was expecting... the following script would work...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "^.*\.php$" "404.html" [L]
RewriteRule "^([^\.]+)$" "$1.php" [L]
```

Comment: i'm no expert but u could try something like `RewriteRule ^.php$ 404.html`

Comment: didn't work. Also tried `(.*)\.php$ 404.html`

Comment: try this, i chked it works: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ 404.html`

Comment: page is simple not found when I use that. It doesn't allow me to use "/test" either

Comment: Awesome.. a random downvote.. hope someone is a little less sad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "^.*\.php$" "404.html" [END]
RewriteRule "^([^\.]+)$" "$1.php" [END]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution [How to remove file extension from website address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

edit: you can do a filematch to prevent executing all .php except index.php. I typically route most of my pages through index.php anyways so this solution would work if you only have a handful of base index files (index1.php,index2.php,etc). I'm sure you can come up with something from this if you don't find a working solution.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "index[0-9]?\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to prevent accessing the file *with* the extension