# Choose HTML directory/domain path/name

Tags: html

I'm making a website, and I'm sorta new to it (haven't published anything yet), and I can't seem to figure out how not to show the "xxx.html/php", so, instead of "domain.com/about.html", it would be "domain.com/about". I see a lot of websites doing this, but I can't seem to figure this out myself, or find a propper way to *ask Google*. Thank you.

Comment: It was asked here :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address

Comment: Take a look at `.htaccess`

Comment: You are searching for "url rewriting" - here you can find a tutorial: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/