# remove .php with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating a .htaccess file in the path of my site `var/www/mysite/` to remove my files the ".php", but does not work

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

It is the first time I do this and if I'm not doing well, or whether this in the right place, so I come to you.

Comment: Check the RewriteLog. After unconditionally always appending a trailing slash, the `RewriteCond /input/path/.php -f` will never match.

Comment: @anubhava For example, I have about.php, redirect about but can not find., But if I redirect to about.php works.

Comment: www.mysite.com/about and failed, but www.mysite.com/about.php its works! @anubhava

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove file extension from website address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address)

Comment: No, it does not work for me, I .htaccess but I still can see my other pages.

Comment: 500 error is generated, nothing happens D:, not that I'll be doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Add trailing slash to url that is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

# Add .php extension from urls internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: I just set up my ubuntu server and I think I have not properly configured Apache, because htaccess that you give me if they work on another server that I have, but driving me crazy lol the conf apache