# How to make a customized url for a html page

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, custom-url

Website source:http://www.salefee.com/

I have a career section in my website which redirects to `http://www.salefee.com/index2.html`

I want that that my url should look like `http://www.salefee.com/career`.
I don't want any `.html` suffix after my url. I have hosted this website using `www.godaddy.com`

Can someone help me with the code. The website is made in html/css.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have access to your `.htaccess` file? You'll need to set some rules in that

Comment: Where is .htacess file located?

Comment: Right in the root - if you haven't seen it, then you probably can't access it. But @C14L answer will work for you

Comment: If you can access the `.htaccess`, then this question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess, or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address

Comment: I have located .htaccess file...what changes do I need to make in that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a subdirectory `/career/` in your web files directory, and then put the HTML file `index.html` in there.

`index.html` is the default file that will be returned by the server when the directory level is accessed by the browser.

Also, for SEO purposes, add a proper `<link rel="canonical" href="/career">` tag in the page header.

Static blog engines like Jekyll or Pelican do it this way too.

There are more methods to achieve that, via Nginx settings or Apache's .htaccess, but since you are on Godaddy you probably need a simple solution.

Comment: Your edit is probably best as a comment... the downvote's not from me tho

Comment: True, I removed the comment from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

This feature is often called "Pretty URLs" or "Permalinks".

So now if you want `http://www.salefee.com/career`, in the same place you put your `index.html` - often called `public_html` - put a `html` file called `career.html`