# How would you make it so when you visit one of your pages on your website, it doesnt have the .html

Tags: javascript, php, html

When you visit a url like https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending it doesnt have .html or .php. Using html or javascript how would I do this? My website is http://www.artsicleprojects.com and when I go to a page like "Nothing" it says `http://artsicleprojects.com/nothing.php`.
So basically, what I want to do is make it so it says

`http://artsicleprojects.com/nothing` when you go to the page

Thanks!

Comment: use htacess for url rewriting  . https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6534969/4248328  OR http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Comment: This is usually accomplished by configuring your webserver properly. For example, Apache may use `RewriteRule` to append an extension behind the scenes or perhaps `AddType` to process untyped (or explicitly named) files through PHP. Questions like this are discussed at [ServerFault @ SE](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Thanks @Anat! This'll help me alot!

Comment: Check this out- [Semantic_URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL). Also you can just put your php files in folders with same names and rename the file as index.php as an easy fix. E.g. `somePath/notes.php` to `somePath/notes/index.php`

Comment: "http://artsicleprojects.com/catclicker/index.php" or you can click it yourself if you want proof :) It only works with the main url artsicleprojects.com for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove file extension from website address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address)

Comment: No, that one didn't help as much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you'd take your `nothing.html`/`nothing.php` file, change the name to `index.html` or `index.php`, then create a folder called 'Nothing', and put your index file there. Then go to www.example.com/nothing, and the `index.html`/`index.php` would automatically run without showing in the URL.

---

`Did this help? If so, please accept my answer. :)`

Comment: I see you have `http://www.artsicleprojects.com/exittheroom/index.php`. Simple remove the /index.php and the page will run the exact same.