# how to show $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; name instead of $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Tags: php, server, localhost, web-hosting

in localhost address contain

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

i tried this code

```
header("location: step2.php?server=".base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

but i want to show only host name i.e means

```
$server=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

---

When i run `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` i get result "`www.apple.com`" only, no "`http://`" no "`/downloads/dashboard/email_messaging/todo.html`"

**i want this result only in address bar**
www.apple.com

Comment: Any reason why you want to achieve this?

Comment: only thing i want to know this, how i can hide file extension in address bar

Comment: File extension as in the .HTML ?

Comment: no, include file name  i.e(cover.html)

Comment: ok i found answer @YATO in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try with this global variable
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Comment: This is a very low quality answer that does not attempt to explain why this is a correct method, nor what exactly it does. (In my opinion, this question is unclear and should not be answered at all.) All answers should endeavor to educate not just the OP, but all future readers. Please improve or remove this answer. Please treat SO like a classroom -- teach.