# Change static HTML Index Page url for Site Homepage

Tags: php, apache, url, mamp

I have a static html site running on MAMP and the home page is the standard index.html page. When I first go to the site from the MAMP menu the url is `http://localhost:8888/sitename`, but when i go back to it from other pages on the site, sometimes the url shows the index.html part i.e. `http://localhost:8888/sitename/index.html`

How do i either change this url to always show `http://localhost:8888/sitename/home.html` or just have `http://localhost:8888/sitename` - and is this even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address

Comment: Thanks Leo - I've found out the problem in my instance - some of the links on my site (i.e. menus etc) had the full path that included index.html which i've changed. I'll  do it as an answer later.

Comment: i think you should keep the index.html inside the links, and do the changed in .htaccess to show the adress as you wish. Or wait for a more professional answer.