# My PHP based website seems to have all broken links

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, cpanel

I've recently bought a PHP script of a website. On the front page, whenever I click on login, or sign up or any other link, I get a *404 error (page not found)*.

The links are of the type: `http://domain.com/login`, `http://domain.com/register`, and so on, but when I check the file manager I found no folder named login or register, etc. Instead there are files like `login.php` and `register.php` and so on. Therefore when I rename the link to `http://domain.com/login.php` or `/register.php`, etc., it works!

Is there a way to correct this problem, apart from editing the links in all the files? Maybe something can be done by changing the `.htaccess` file.

P.S.: I use cpanel.

I checked my `.htaccess` file and found this (is there anything I need to edit in there?):

```
options -multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^conversations/([^/.]*)?$ conversations.php?u=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
# Turn off mod_security filtering. 
SecFilterEngine Off 
# The below probably isn't needed, 
# but better safe than sorry. 
SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you might want to have a look into .htaccess and or your apache config (mod_rewrite)

Comment: Sounds like a `mod_rewrite` problem. Is it installed? Is the according `.htaccess` present?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Read the script's manual or ask the creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't seem to work. can you check my update ?

Comment: No where in your .htaccess I see code as suggested by me here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `.htaccess` file to rewrite the URL to remove the .php extension and redirect traffic to the correct scripts.

For more details, see [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Remove .php extension with .htaccess*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess#answer-4026967).