# .htaccess remove .php and force trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have files in my root folder. `jobs.php`, `contact.php`.

I want to be able to use .htaccess to remove the `.php` extension and force a trailing slash `/`. So that, `www.domain.com/jobs/` and `www.domain.com/contact/` goes to their respective pages.

Also, I want `jobs.domain.com` to point to `www.domain.com/jobs/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(rosquillos)/$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

This is what I've got so far, and as much as I try. I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be awesome.

EDIT:

I would like to rephrase my question. The existing code removes the `.php` extensions for me, what I really only need right now is an additional rule that points the subdomain to the correct file: ie. `jobs.domain.com` points to jobs.php. I can live without the trailing slash.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php` for job `RewriteRule ^jobs/$ jobs.php`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

will fail if your URL's end with a trailing slash. But if you only have `jobs` and `contact` then you'll just want:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash and redirect browser
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.php [L]

# redirect direct access to php files:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```

Oh and I forgot:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

Assuming that `*.domain.com` has the same document root as `www.domain.com`.

Comment: This one has the added benefit of forcing all links to include the trailing slash.

Comment: but I don't have /just/ jobs and contact. how do I make it so that it accepts any page? Just replace it with `*`?

Comment: @DumbAsker Try replacing `(jobs|contact)` with `([^/]+)`

Comment: Looks great, I'll try this out as soon as I can. My laptop bugged out and I'm still migrating stuff over to a new unit.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and actually gives me weird results. I would like to rephrase my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @DumbAsker The stuff after "Oh I forgot" deals with the subdomains