# Clean / SEO friendly urls for e107 system version 1.0.4

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched all over the net and this site too ( trust me on that :( ) but couldn't find a simpler solution instead of manual `.htaccess` rewrite for every single url.

So ... Is there a plugin or easier way, to rewrite **all** e107 systems urls as SEO friendly ones?

I am using v1.0.4 ( since the 2.0 is still in *alpha* stage ).

I just hate see them as

[image]

instead of just `/news/` or

[image]

instead of just `/forum/` etc.

Comment: Does this help at all?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: Sorry m8, it does not. I know how to rewrite, but I'm trying to find an easier way to do this for this particular system. It is giving me a headache that I cant do anything about. I just refuse to believe, that e107 has no *normal* way to create clean urls.

Comment: If there is no predictable pattern, then you'll have to do it individually

Comment: @JonLin That's what I'm afraid of and the options are way too many for the *comfort zone* :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so this might not be exactly what I was looking for, but as close as it gets.

[Spinning Planet's SEO module](http://e107.org/e107_plugins/psilo/list.php?mode=plugin&cat=0&id=1256) let's you create and manage rewrite rules the easy way.

With some manual url rewrite in `theme.php` and this plugin I got pretty much all of the important urls rewritten.

Answer (score -1):

In e107 v1.0 there is no core SEO or FURL support. The suggested Spinning Planet SEO plugin is probably your best shot for v1.0. As of e107 Booststrap CMS (formerly known as v2) friendly URLS will be part of the core functionality. However, this version is still in ALPHA stage.
See: https://github.com/e107inc/e107