# Removing .php also messes up folders

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

So I'm using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To get rid of the `.php` in my URL. So here's what happens. I have a folder named `good`, and an `index.php` inside it, now when I go to `localhost/good` I end up getting a 404 not found. I assume that this is because of my .htaccess. Any ideas?

Comment: That `RewriteCond` is commonly accompanied by another one for `-d` directories.

Comment: Albeit checking for existence of the .php script is the better option: [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4908122)