# Remove php extension on localhost apache server?

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to get the `.php` extension to not be required when you view a php file. My current config is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/server
    ServerName localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

However, it doesn't work as I'm getting 404's when I try access a files like `login.php` as login, for instance. My server setup is kind of strange, in the `/var/www/server` is a symbolic link to another folder `Dev/server/`. Also, since it's `localhost`, I'm accessing it via `localhost/project/login.php`.

Comment: For starters is `RewriteEngine On`?  This looks like a nice write up on the topic: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: I added that above the RewriteRule, and still the same thing. I'll check out that link :)

Comment: Hmm, okay. So I just tried what the article suggested and it didn't work, but... I have other projects in my server folder too, and I tried those and they worked. I think it might be because the project has a dot in the folder name?

Comment: Yup! Perhaps an important detail I overlooked, because the projects folder had a dot in the name, it must've gotten confused.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that regex rule looks like it would fail if the URI contained periods in the path.  Which is bad since RFC does not say they are not valid.

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^\\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That would result in: `http://test.com/test/test.test/test.php` for a request like `http://test.com/test/test.test/test`

I would test it more though.  You might want to take a look at an .htaccess tester like this: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

The `REQUEST_FILENAME` can be swapped out for `REQUEST_URI` if needed in testing.