# Having clean URLs throughout

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I am creating a website and cannot figure out how to set clean URLs throughout all my webpages. Is there a way to do this without `.htaccess`? If no how can I accomplish with it? I'm using Apache.

This is an example of what I have now, which I do not want:

```
www.example.com/about.html
```

This is what I want the URL to look like:

```
www.example.com/about/
```

Comment: What type of server are you on?

Comment: I am on an apache server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

For `.html` you can code below, it will rewrite request when you `.html` is enter in url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Comment: Hello Tengku. Could you explain how the code works and where to place it. Thanks :)

Comment: should be in `httpd.conf`, check this doc. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Apache is configured differently, the file `/about/index.html` will be returned under the URL `/about/`.

By default, Apache looks for a file named `index.html`, but this can be changed with the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Answer (score 0):

You must create the file .htaccess in your server and add this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```