# Is it possible to condence my htaccess Rewrite rules into a single line rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

All the htaccess rules in my Webproject do their job. However, I wonder if there is any way around to write a single rule using REGEX instead of hard-coding them as shown below. I couldn't find question/answers on SO that address the need mentioned here. Thanks for any advice or help.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index                               index.php 
RewriteRule ^about-us                            about-us.php
RewriteRule ^web-application-development         web-application-development.php
RewriteRule ^mobile-application-development      mobile-application-development.php
RewriteRule ^offshoring                          offshoring.php
RewriteRule ^internet-marketing                  internet-marketing.php
RewriteRule ^careers                             careers.php
RewriteRule ^blog                                blog.php
RewriteRule ^contact-us                          contact-us.php
```

I am looking for a single rule involving REGEX that does the job that all the rules above do when put together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule to rewrite your .php requests

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Alternatively ,you could enable multivies to access files without extensions, add the following line to your htaccess.

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Yours is much simpler one. Great.