# Creating multiple HTML pages in 1 file?

Tags: html, video

I've **just** started learning HTML and I'm I've begun to make my own website (for fun) and was wondering how I load a certain video depending on the '/'.

`localhost/video1
localhost/video2`

rather than having, possibly, hundreds of .html files for each video, is there a way to simply get the video/file depending on the contents as the code is the same, the video is only different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

- You could use Javascript to get anchor hashes for your page. The urls are then looking like `localhost/#video1`

  [How can you check for a #hash in a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript)
- Use instead of plain HTML files, for example php. With mod_rewrite you can rewrite `localhost/video1.php` into `localhost/video1` [Removing the .php extension with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)
- A third option is to use a router library like http://smalljs.org/client-side-routing/page/ or http://projects.jga.me/routie/

Comment: Do you know how '?v=KEY' works? used on sites, such as YouTube

Comment: This a so called GET parameters, which you can grab server side. For example in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php