# mod_rewrite not working when url string is the name of an existing file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is to remove the php file extension needed for the url,

i.e. myipaddress/abc -> myipaddress/abc.php

However I can't seem to get mod_rewrite to work using the solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite).

My .htaccess file contains these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1c.php [L]
```

So if i have a file named abc.php on my server and my url in the browser is "myipaddress/ab", abc.php will be properly shown. Any file that cannot be found will return me a internal server error (since the third cond is commented out).

In this case i get this to work:

myipaddress/ab -> myipaddress/abc.php

Now if i change the last line like this (which is the answer provided):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Now if I have a file named abc.php and i put in myipaddress/abc, i get a 404 not found which says

```
Not Found

The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.
```

If i look up for other links like abcd.php which is not on my server, i still get a 500 internal server error. However when i try a link like myipaddress/name and if name.php is on my server, i get a 404. I'm very confused by the fact that if the url contains name, mod_rewrite will not rewrite the url and have spent hours on it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you have automatic content negotiation enabled on your system. You want to disable it.

Comment: @arkascha My server is ubuntu 16.04 and apache version is 2.4.1. Can you be more specific on how i can do that?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Comment: @arkascha Thank you! I have disabled it and it works! many thanks!

Comment: Ok, great to hear. I added an answer which you might want to accept, so that others can find this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have automatic content negotiation enabled on your system. You want to disable it.

Take a look into the documentation. It is well written and comes with lots of great examples:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html