# My Apacher server render php file even when .php extension is present

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Some people want to access `.php` files without the extension. For example :

> Accessing `example.com/user.php?id=42` via `example.com/user/42`

My problem is : I don't want it. Even without any `.htaccess` file at all, when I go to `mywebsite.com/foo` it will render then serve `mywebsite.com/foo.php`.

How can I prevent this ?

My original problem is the following :

> I want to rewrite `mywebsite.com/user/grades/foo/bar` to `mywebsite.com/user/grades.php?user=foo&exam=bar`

But, it won't work because Apache will render `grades.php` even without the extension. The rewrite won't work because the original URL exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @NightKing no, it does the contrary. This answer allows somebody to redirect foo to foo.php Me, I want to connect to /foo and not be redirected to /foo.php

Comment: dont know if thats possible, as the whole idea behind mod_rewrite was this but u can try routing all request to a front controller which then calls other php this may allow you to utilize that sort of url arrangement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the [`MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) option:

```
Options -MultiViews
```