# Hidden Rules in Apache Level?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos7, whm

Just got a new dedicated server from a reputable hosting company for my new website project.

It runs Centos 7.9/WHM with Apache 2.4+PHP 7.4 Package.
PHP-FPM as handler.

I ran some test with some php files in my website folder and I noticed that any .php files is accessible without his extension. Without any .htaccess file!

"https://www.example.com/myinfo.php" is Accessible.

"https://www.example.com/myinfo" Should be inaccessible without any .htaccess + rules.

It's annoying me a lot because I know it's gonna bring me some issues during my website project.

Where could these rule be as I am not using any htaccess file?

Thanks for any information you can give me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Sounds like you could be having [multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled in your vhost. Try turning them off, restart apache and check if the issue is resolved. There could also be rewrite rules directly in your vhost.

Comment: Multiviews must be the problem. Or atleast a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

As [Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) said: You could be having [multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled in your vhost. Try turning them off, restart apache and check if the issue is resolved. There could also be rewrite rules directly in your vhost.

As you have cPanel installed, my guess is the `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`, and `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.default`. Before you edit the `ea4_main.default`, copy it to `ea4_main.local`: `cp -a /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.default /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.local`, and only edit the `ea4_main.local` file. Please be careful when editing it, as it could mess up a lot of things. I would suggest you to ask questions on [cPanel Forums](https://forums.cpanel.net) if you are using cPanel, because this must be a cPanel related issue. **And, I am not responsible if any problems occur, I have warned you already.**

### Edit:

Since you linked your httpd.conf file, I found this:

```
<Directory "/">
    
      AllowOverride All
    
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC Indexes ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Change it to:

```
<Directory "/">
    
      AllowOverride All
    
    Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNOEXEC +Indexes +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already had a look at Multiviews but It doesn't change anything. I also checked the httpd.conf and ea4_main.default files as you suggested me but I can't really see wha't wrong inside. How that kind of custom rule looks like? I am not a server guy. I am gonna post my question on cPanel Forum too, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @joe, you probably cannot get an answer other than this. Because MultiViews is the only culprit visible. Provide the httpd.conf file in your question. And also ea4.conf.local.

Comment: @joe, I request you to post the cpanel forums thread here, so that I can assist you better there.

Comment: @joe, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux, it might help you find which file has the MultiViews setting.

Comment: Here is my httpd.conf https://controlc.com/de0a7ad4 and ea4_main.default https://controlc.com/05228245

Comment: Didn't you see this:  `Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC Indexes ExecCGI`. Remove MultiViews from httpd.conf. It is in about line 60 in httpd.conf.