# Apache Clean URL Code Causing An Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, clean-urls, custom-error-pages

I'm setting up a 404 page on a project on my localhost (MAMP) and in my `.htaccess` file I’ve included the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8888/project/public/404.php
```

The 404.php page sits at the same level as `.htaccess` file in a public folder below the project root:

```
project
— publicFolder
— privateFolder
```

**The Issue**

When I include the code within the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` it throws an error when I type in a 404 page URL (i.e. a page that doesn't exist). When I remove this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` code block the problem goes away. The error message is:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

When I check the apache error log, as recommended in the above message I get the following:

```
[core:error] [pid 2575] [client ::1:51038] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I suspect the issue may be to do with the line that removes the `.php` file extension on all of the pages, i.e.`RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC,L]`

**My Question**

How do I get the clean URL code inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block to stop throwing an internal server error when a user goes to what should be a 404 page?

Any help great appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing the .php extension with mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue simply is that you indeed implement an endless rewriting loop.

Have a try using that variant with an additional condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

You need to understand that the `L` flag you are using indeed terminates the rewriting, *but only for the current cycle* . Whenever a rewriting cycle alters (rewrites) the processed request a *new* cycle is started. Until the request is stable, so is *not* rewritten again. Since the rewritten target *again* matches your conditions *and* the rule's matching pattern you *again* rewrite the request in your implementation. Which ultimately results in a request to something like `/foo.php.php.php.php.php`, appending one ".php" for every rewriting cycle.

An alternative would be to use the younger `[END]`¸ flag here instead of the older `[L]` flag. The END flag *completely* terminates the rewriting process, ignoring any other rules. So you need to be sure that rule really is the last that should get applied. Using that flag you won't need the additional condition, since the complete termination obviously prevents an endless rewriting loop.

---

In general I would advise to *not* use distributed configuration files for this (".htaccess"). But to implement such rules in the actual http server's central host configuration. And use *absolute* paths there.

That typically prevents a lot of confusing and side effects.

---

Certainly there may be other issues here that do not get immediately clear from the question you asked. But above is an obvious issue.

Always test using a fresh anonymous browser window, always make *deep* reloads in the browser to prevent client side caching effects while testing.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer. Very helpful.