# hide file name extensions in url?

Tags: .htaccess

can some help me please i am wanting to hide the file name extension in the url of my site.

so an example would be 
http://www.mysite.com/home.php
http://www.mysite.com/control.php

would instead show as
http://www.mysite.com/home
http://www.mysite.com/control

i have been looking into this and found this code which seems to hide the file name extension in the url but now my links wont work and im getting a 404 error. i think that i need to amend my site link paths or something like that.

can someone show me what i need to do please, here's the code im using in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Google can help before stack :)

```
   RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/
Also lookat
[Making a rewriterule remove .php extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781738/making-a-rewriterule-remove-php-extension)

Comment: If you call.  R<root>/control/ it will load controlled.html

Comment: I've added a link to a previous question like this have a gander

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all the extensions (not just .php, .html) then use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

in your httpd.conf or .htaccess

Comment: You need to remove all your existing rules first and try with above line only. Also make sure .htaccess is indeed enabled. Finally to just to let you this fully tested solution on our web servers.